# drawing complex dependency diagrams with tikz / forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

I want to draw the following Word Grammar diagram with `tikz`/`forest`:
[image]

I am a great fan of `forest`and would like to have a style for such graphs, but I think this is non-trivial/impossible for this type of diagrams since the tree nodes are split into several instances (for instance: children, children', and children''). So what I would do is to use a table, put text in boxes into it and draw the connectors by explicit commands. Or is there a more "stylish" way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An idea is to signal split nodes using nodes with empty content. More precisely, style `wg` is defined to fill the content of an empty node with the content of its parent. Also, it appends a `'` to the parents content.

To make drawing of dependency arrows easier, nodes are given names based on their content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{
  wg/.style={
    for tree={
      no edge,
      draw,
      outer ysep=1pt,
    },
    copy label/.style={
      for children={
        if content={}{
            content/.pgfmath={content("!u")},
            calign with current,
            edge={draw,{-Triangle[open,reversed]}},
            copy label,
            !u.content/.pgfmath={content},
            !u.content+=',
        }{
          copy label,
        }
      }
    },
    delay={
      copy label,
      for tree={name/.pgfmath={content}},
    },
    for tree={content format={\strut\forestoption{content}}},
    where n children={0}{
      tier=word,
    }{},
  },
}
\tikzset{deparrow/.style={-Latex,blue}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  wg
  [were
    [children
      [
        [small]
        []
      ]
    ]
    [
      []
    ]
    [playing
      [
        []
        [outside]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \draw[deparrow] (were'') to[out=west, in=north] (children'');
  \draw[deparrow] (children') to[out=west, in=north] (small);
  \draw[deparrow] (were') to[out=60, in=120] (playing'');
  \draw[deparrow] (playing'') to[out=220, in=east] (children');
  \draw[deparrow] (playing') to[out=east, in=north] (outside);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I now tried to do a simplified version of the diagram and noticed that one could draw most of the arrows automatically. It would be great if you could have a look at the new question as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256651/drawing-condensed-version-of-complex-dependency-diagrams Thanks a lot!