# Getting (automatic) space between lines so that labels fit in

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I got code for drawing dependency grammar trees ([drawing complex dependency diagrams with tikz / forest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256280/drawing-complex-dependency-diagrams-with-tikz-forest/256300#256300)). I now added labels to the dependency arrows, but this does not look nice, since the space between the arrows is not sufficent. Is there a way to get more space for all these arrows and their descriptions automatically? I think glaubst-dass, habe-ich and dass-habe have to be higher.

This is what I have:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{deparrow/.style={-Latex}}%,blue}}


\forestset{
 wg/.style={
    for tree={
      no edge,
      draw,
      outer ysep=1pt,
    },
    copy label/.style={
      for children={
        if content={}{
            content/.pgfmath={content("!u")},
            calign with current,
            edge={draw,{-Triangle[open,reversed]}},
            copy label,
            !u.content/.pgfmath={content},
            !u.content+=',
        }{
          copy label,
        }
      }
    },
    delay={
      copy label,
      for tree={name/.pgfmath={content}},
    },
    for tree={content format={\strut\forestoption{content}}},
    where n children={0}{
      tier=word,
    }{},
  },
}


    \begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  wg
  [,phantom
   [wen]
   [glaubst]
   [du]
   [dass]
   [ich]
   [gesehen]
   [habe]
  ]
\draw[deparrow] ([xshift=-0pt]glaubst.north) to[out=north, in=north] node[above] {s}     ([xshift= 0pt]du.north);
\draw[deparrow] ([xshift=-3pt]glaubst.north) to[out=north, in=north] node[above] {c}     ([xshift=-3pt]dass.north);
\draw[deparrow] ([xshift= 3pt]dass.north)    to[out=north, in=north] node[above] {c}     ([xshift= 3pt]habe.north);
\draw[deparrow] ([xshift=-3pt]habe.north)    to[out=north, in=north] node[above] {r}     ([xshift= 0pt]gesehen.north);
\draw[deparrow] ([xshift=-3pt]habe.north)    to[out=north, in=north] node[above] {s}     ([xshift= 0pt]ich.north);
%
\draw[deparrow] ([xshift= 0pt]gesehen.south) to[out=south, in=south] node[below] {x$<$o} ([xshift=-3pt]wen.south);
\draw[deparrow] ([xshift= 0pt]dass.south)    to[out=south, in=south] node[below] {x$<$}  ([xshift= 0pt]wen.south);
\draw[deparrow] ([xshift= 0pt]glaubst.south) to[out=south, in=south] node[below] {x$<$}  ([xshift= 3pt]wen.south);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define controll points for the bezier curve which is, of course, not an automatic solution:

```
\draw[deparrow] ([xshift=-0pt]glaubst.north) .. controls +(up:6mm) and +(up:6mm) .. node[above] {s}  ([xshift= 0pt]du.north);
\draw[deparrow] ([xshift=-3pt]glaubst.north) .. controls +(up:12mm) and +(up:12mm) .. node[above] {c} ([xshift=-3pt]dass.north);
```

Comment: Thanks! There are so many options to control the behaviour of these arrows. I did not know the `up` option. I could imagine an automatic solution that is suboptimal: one could incremt the `up`-value.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to increase the `looseness` of the curve, which allows you to keep the current syntax otherwise unaltered. For example:

```
...
  \draw[deparrow] ([xshift=-3pt]glaubst.north) to[out=north, in=north, looseness=1.2] node[above] {c}     ([xshift=-3pt]dass.north);
  \draw[deparrow] ([xshift= 3pt]dass.north)    to[out=north, in=north, looseness=1.5] node[above] {c}     ([xshift= 3pt]habe.north);
...
  \draw[deparrow] ([xshift=-3pt]habe.north)    to[out=north, in=north, looseness=1.2] node[above] {s}     ([xshift= 0pt]ich.north);
```

will increase the `looseness` of the three curves in question:

[image: space for labels]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{deparrow/.style={-Latex}}
\forestset{
 wg/.style={
    for tree={
      no edge,
      draw,
      outer ysep=1pt,
    },
    copy label/.style={
      for children={
        if content={}{
            content/.pgfmath={content("!u")},
            calign with current,
            edge={draw,{-Triangle[open,reversed]}},
            copy label,
            !u.content/.pgfmath={content},
            !u.content+=',
        }{
          copy label,
        }
      }
    },
    delay={
      copy label,
      for tree={name/.pgfmath={content}},
    },
    for tree={content format={\strut\forestoption{content}}},
    where n children={0}{
      tier=word,
    }{},
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  wg
  [,phantom
   [wen]
   [glaubst]
   [du]
   [dass]
   [ich]
   [gesehen]
   [habe]
  ]
  \draw[deparrow] ([xshift=-0pt]glaubst.north) to[out=north, in=north] node[above] {s}     ([xshift= 0pt]du.north);
  \draw[deparrow] ([xshift=-3pt]glaubst.north) to[out=north, in=north, looseness=1.2] node[above] {c}     ([xshift=-3pt]dass.north);
  \draw[deparrow] ([xshift= 3pt]dass.north)    to[out=north, in=north, looseness=1.5] node[above] {c}     ([xshift= 3pt]habe.north);
  \draw[deparrow] ([xshift=-3pt]habe.north)    to[out=north, in=north] node[above] {r}     ([xshift= 0pt]gesehen.north);
  \draw[deparrow] ([xshift=-3pt]habe.north)    to[out=north, in=north, looseness=1.2] node[above] {s}     ([xshift= 0pt]ich.north);
  \draw[deparrow] ([xshift= 0pt]gesehen.south) to[out=south, in=south] node[below] {x$<$o} ([xshift=-3pt]wen.south);
  \draw[deparrow] ([xshift= 0pt]dass.south)    to[out=south, in=south] node[below] {x$<$}  ([xshift= 0pt]wen.south);
  \draw[deparrow] ([xshift= 0pt]glaubst.south) to[out=south, in=south] node[below] {x$<$}  ([xshift= 3pt]wen.south);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```